# Android, make text switcher central?

Tags: android

How can I centralise my text switcher? I've tried set gravity but it doesnt seem to work.

```
ts.setFactory(new ViewFactory() {
        public View makeView() {
        TextView t = new TextView(this);
        t.setTypeface(tf);
        t.setTextSize(20);
        t.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        t.setText("my text switcher");
        t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        return t;
    }
    });
```

Comment: if you want to put your textview in center, then I think you used some parent layout and then apply android:layout_gravity="center". try this. Thanks.

Comment: How can I add gravity to a linear layout programatically? Rather than xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is OK, you need to set the **parent textSwitcher** width to fill_parent

either in XML with

```
<TextSwitcher android:layout_width="fill_parent" ...
```

or in code

```
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
//...
textSwitcher=...
textSwitcher.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: is possible to get text of textswitcher in runtime

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `match_parent` or a fixed value for the TextSwitcher size, do the following. In the .xml:

```
<TextSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/switcher"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"/>
```

In code:

```
    import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;

    TextSwitcher mSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
    mSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewFactory() {
        @Override
        public View makeView() {
            TextView t = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            t.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            return t;
        }
    });
```

It is quite important to set LayoutParams to `MATCH_PARENT` to get the TextSwitcher centered vertically.