# Android TextSwitcher centered on a Android ButtonView

Tags: android, button

I have four buttons where I want a text switcher to change the text when another button is selected. For my switcher I want the text to be centered inside of the button view, I would
like to know how this can be done as I am having a hard time getting the text to center inside of the button
.

Answer (score 1):

TextSwitcher animates the current text out and animates the new text in.  so

**On create**

```
    private TextSwitche  mSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
        mSwitcher.setFactory(this);
 Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and

```
public View makeView() {
        Button b= new Button(this);
        b.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
       b.setTextSize(70);
        b.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        return b;
    }
```

**in xml**

```
   <Button android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="one"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />  
     <Button android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Switch"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />                                         
   <TextSwitcher android:id="@+id/switcher"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I have not tested this code but i think it help for you.if you want more information about textSwitcher go to its [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextSwitcher.html).
and [Android, make text switcher central?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662283/android-make-text-switcher-central)

Comment: Ok I am going to give this try, as I have my switcher and viewfactory set up, just wanted to find out how to center the text from the text switcher inside the button view.